# React Router fail to direct access subpage when deployed

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, web-deployment, webdeploy

When I am working in localhost, using create-react-app

I am able to access localhost:3000/A or localhost:3000/B

But when I deploy it to the server, npm build run and put the built file to the server folder like to the https://ip/project_name

I can click in the `<Link/>` to go to  https://ip/project_name/A or https://ip/project_name/B
but I cannot direct access to  https://ip/project_name/A.

App.js

```
<BrowserRouter basename={'project_name'}>
    <Route path='/A' component={A}/>
    <Route path='/B' component={B}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Link

```
<Link to="/A">A</Link>
<Link to="/B">B</Link>
```

package.json

```
"homepage": ".",
...
"dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem is in the server folder, the react router setting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with string for basename prop?

```
<BrowserRouter basename="project_name">
    <Route path='/A' component={A}/>
    <Route path='/B' component={B}/>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Both are the same

Answer (score 0):

For posterity :

You have to add a rewrite rule in your web server : For example, Rewrite /* as /index.html

It should solve your problem.

Why :
For static site with dynamic (react) pages, the web server serves the main file index.html only and some static files like css, images, etc.

Once index.html is loaded, react-router is then used to select the correct page, depending on the resource path on the url path.

If there is no rewrite rule, a path like https://ip/project_name/A request a resource 'A' on the server. So index.html is never retrieved and you get a 404 status code.

Answer (score 0):

Just use HashRouter without basename instead of BrowserRouter:

```
import { HashRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// Then in render
<HashRouter>
  <Route path='/' component={ Home } exact />
  <Route path='/contact' component={ Contact} exact />
</HashRouter>
```

Note that you’ll have /#/ included in URLs:

http://server.com/path/#/contact